# How to login user from java code in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I am trying to write some script in my java code, where i need to login users, do some stuff like real user could do from web client and logout for each of them.

How does this work in spring security?
What should i do?
I mean how to imitate user authentication like in real, with session, roles and authorities?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few time later i found solution:

```
@Component
public class AuthorityUtils {

//org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public void loginDirectly(String email, String password) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loginToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);
    Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(loginToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this Example :

create Spring Security Java Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/list")
                .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
                .antMatchers("/newuser/**", "/delete-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").antMatchers("/edit-user-*")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password").and()
                .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }

}
```

Spring Security comes with two implementation of **PersistentTokenRepository** : **JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl** and **InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl**.

```
@Repository("tokenRepositoryDao")
@Transactional
public class HibernateTokenRepositoryImpl extends AbstractDao<String, PersistentLogin>
        implements PersistentTokenRepository {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateTokenRepositoryImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void createNewToken(PersistentRememberMeToken token) {
        logger.info("Creating Token for user : {}", token.getUsername());
        PersistentLogin persistentLogin = new PersistentLogin();
        persistentLogin.setUsername(token.getUsername());
        persistentLogin.setSeries(token.getSeries());
        persistentLogin.setToken(token.getTokenValue());
        persistentLogin.setLast_used(token.getDate());
        persist(persistentLogin);

    }

    @Override
    public PersistentRememberMeToken getTokenForSeries(String seriesId) {
        logger.info("Fetch Token if any for seriesId : {}", seriesId);
        try {
            Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("series", seriesId));
            PersistentLogin persistentLogin = (PersistentLogin) crit.uniqueResult();

            return new PersistentRememberMeToken(persistentLogin.getUsername(), persistentLogin.getSeries(),
                    persistentLogin.getToken(), persistentLogin.getLast_used());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Token not found...");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUserTokens(String username) {
        logger.info("Removing Token if any for user : {}", username);
        Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        PersistentLogin persistentLogin = (PersistentLogin) crit.uniqueResult();
        if (persistentLogin != null) {
            logger.info("rememberMe was selected");
            delete(persistentLogin);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void updateToken(String seriesId, String tokenValue, Date lastUsed) {
        logger.info("Updating Token for seriesId : {}", seriesId);
        PersistentLogin persistentLogin = getByKey(seriesId);
        persistentLogin.setToken(tokenValue);
        persistentLogin.setLast_used(lastUsed);
        update(persistentLogin);
    }

}
```

Above implementation uses an Entity [PersistentLogin] mapped to persistent_logins table, shown below is the entity itself.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSISTENT_LOGINS")
public class PersistentLogin implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private String series;

    @Column(name="USERNAME", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="TOKEN", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String token;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date last_used;

    public String getSeries() {
        return series;
    }

    public void setSeries(String series) {
        this.series = series;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public Date getLast_used() {
        return last_used;
    }

    public void setLast_used(Date last_used) {
        this.last_used = last_used;
    }


}
```

The UserDetailsService implementation, used in Security configuration is shown below:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findBySSO(ssoId);
        logger.info("User : {}", user);
        if(user==null){
            logger.info("User not found");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getSsoId(), user.getPassword(), 
                 true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }


    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(UserProfile userProfile : user.getUserProfiles()){
            logger.info("UserProfile : {}", userProfile);
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+userProfile.getType()));
        }
        logger.info("authorities : {}", authorities);
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

Finally, register the springSecurityFilter with application war using below mentioned initializer class.

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Comment: share whit us ur knowledge or if u have better idea.. instead of voting down without any reason !

Comment: If you asking me, i had not voted down. 
To be honest, I just saw, coming to work and voted up 
for a detailed response. Also i do not know, why somebody voted down the question. At least two person made this question favorite.

Comment: I know it wasn't you.. ;)